# How can I allow one column to auto-resize, while giving another a fixed position?

Tags: html, css

I wrote the following code, and it is a mess.

I want `left-sbr` and `right-sbr` in a fixed position but let `content` auto-resize based on the browser or window's resolution. How can I do this?

```
.left-sbr{
width:240px;
color:#2d2d2d;
float:left;
border:1px solid #0066FF;
position:fixed;
top:33px;
left:43px;
}
.content{
/*width:500px;*/
margin:33px 1px 0px 287px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;
position:absolute;
width:50%;
/*left:287px;
top:33px;*/
height:100%;
color:#2d2d2d;
float:left;
border:1px solid #0066FF;
}
.right-sbr{
/*margin:33px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;*/
width:23%;
position:absolute;
top:33px;
left:100%;
color:#2d2d2d;
float:right;
border:1px solid #0066FF;
}
```

Here's the HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Learning English Grammar for Non Native Speakers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="in-design.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="left-sbr">
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
</div>
<div class="content">Data pada komputer diolah dan simpan dalam bentuk digital atau bilangan biner. Digital hanya mngenal dua nilai saja yaitu : 0 dan 1. Setiap 0 dan 1, disebut dengan istilah bit (binary digit). Bilangan yang terdiri atas delapan nilai (misalnya 10001001) disebut dengan byte (8 bit).<br>
Dalam dunia digital, ada dua jenis basis satuan, definisi basis 2 dan basis 10. Pada basis10, satu kilo berarti 1000 sedangkan pada basis 2 berarti 210 =1024. Berikut tabel basis satuan yang  perlu anda ketahui: Ukuran Definisi basis 2 Defenisi basis 101 kilobytes 1024 byter 1000 bytes1 megabytes 1024 KB=1.048.576 bytes 1000.000 bytes1 gigabytes 1024 MB=1.073.741.824 bytes 1000.000.000 bytes.<br>
</div>
<div class="right-sbr">
cccccccccccccccccc</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want, then you can try this (without jquery):

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
#content { position:absolute; width:100%; height:100%; color:white; }
.left-sbr { float:left; margin:0px 0px; width:25%; height:100%; background:green; }
.content-center { float:left; margin:0px 0px; width:50%; height:100%; background:grey; }
.right-sbr { float:right; margin:0px 0px; width:25%; height:100%; background:blue; }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="content">
  <div class="left-sbr">left</div>
  <div class="content-center">center or content (as you want)</div>
  <div class="right-sbr">right</div>
</div>
```

Comment: it is 3 columns (left-content-right), both left and right sidebar you give works indeed, but what about content? ... I mean, I want it(content) auto resized depends on windows resolution or browser.

Comment: You want, that content will be in the center of page? About resizing: you can use `@media only screen and (max-width: your width) { }` And yes, it is pure css.

Comment: hihihi .. it works!!!. MAX-WIDTH .. then I just customize it into procentage I want .. Thanks so much ^_^ thanks again :D
As you know, I try not using jquery or javascript to make my page loading fast (SEO approach, right?) :D